# Django read Static JSON file directly using Ajax call?

Tags: ajax, django

It may not sounds good, but in my case I have static json files in the application and I want read them directly using AJAX call without having to create separate service call.A separate service call is required because URL pattern does not match and so I will get 404.

Can I achieve this in Django?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^xurl/', method1),
    url(r'^yurl/', method2),
]
```

AJAX:

```
 $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
        $("/ZURL").html(result);
    }});
```

if you take a look at the url patterns, ajax sends request ZURL in this case, but URL patteren is not defined Django url pattren.

Since I have allready have few json files at ZURL location and I don't want create seprate service method to read json file form the django and send same file back to browser.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Django itself doesn't serve static files, that's a job for your webserver. But why would you think this wouldn't be possible?

Comment: Why don't you directly serve those JSON files using a webserver like nginx? What is the role of Django in this?